# IntelliJ - Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, 64-bit, windows-7-x64

Whenever trying to run a Java application. I'm experiencing this stacktrace error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

---

Current Environment Configuration

- IntelliJ Ultimate Edition 2016.1.3
- JDK 7 (64 bit)
- Windows 7 (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

You need to 64-bit SWT library to load it into a 64-bit process.

A 64-bit process (JVM or not) cannot load a 32-bit shared library in Windows, UNIX or MacOSX.  This is a limitation of the OS not the JVM.  Basically, you can't pass a 64-bit address to a 32-bit library, so they can't interact with one another.

Comment: So I'll need to provide a 32-bit JVM (JDK/JRE) and configure it to the run configuration while having the working environment on 64-bit?

Comment: @CyrilHorad This is part of the joy of using native libraries, they have to have the same bitness as the process which loads them. And you have to have the appropriate one for the each platform you use. Which is a good reason to avoid using them IMHO.